# Panadas read_csv not delimiting table correctly

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-wrangling

I am trying to load a messy csv into a data frame for some data wrangling but am having troubles getting Pandas to recognize the columns (delimited by ','). I have tried using the 'sep' and 'delimiter' arguments to no avail. Here is the link to the dataset: https://github.com/metmuseum/openaccess

Here is the code I am loading the csv with:

```
## Load dataset to dataframe
art_df = pd.read_csv('MetObjects.csv', delimiter=',', keep_default_na=True, sep=',')

## Display first 10 records
art_df.head(n=10)
```

but it is loading it as such into one column:
[image: Sample DF]

Comment: For me working well, I think you can try upgrade pandas.

Comment: I am using the latest version. Update: I read straight from github and it imported correctly, but not when using the .csv file I downloaded from the same source. Any ideas why?

Comment: @MikeZoucha did you ever find the issue? I am having the same problem